# What is the purpose of the third-party-cookie phase-out?

Tags: cookies, w3c

I've recently been reading about Chromium trying to phase out third-party cookies, and the project confuses me a bit. Most of the documentation I can find about it relate to technical issues and migration to alternative systems, and I haven't been able to find any documentation about the core intentions behind it.

Much of the documentation I have found, for example [here](https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/privacy-sandbox/third-party-cookie-phase-out/), briefly mentions that third-party cookies are being phased out because they are being used for tracking. An understandable and laudable purpose, but it strikes me as unbelievably naïve (in the literal sense of the term). If tracking pixels and similar mechanisms cannot use third-party cookies any longer, then *surely* the solution that sites using them are going to find is not going to involve ceasing tracking, but rather to move to first-party cookies and tighter server-side integration with the tracking services? Unless I'm missing something fundamental here, this seems obvious to me.

That's why I'm wondering if I'm missing something about the whole phase-out. Do the people behind it actually believe that it will lead to less tracking on the web, or is the purpose different from how I'm understanding it?

I understand that this question may sound opinionated and thus not be a good fit for StackOverflow, but that's not my intention. I'm genuinely just wondering what I'm missing, or if there are technical reasons to believe that it will actually lead to less tracking.